# framer motion exit animation does not update as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am having problems applying framer motion exit animations in React.
My application requires building an image slider that shows an animation after changing an image.

while pressing the buttons to change images all animations work ok. However, if we change directions (for example slide down and then up) the exit animation does not update the first time and goes in the opposite direction.

here is a repro:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-vaughan-nbnlsm?file=/src/App.js

I understand that this problem is caused because the element is already loaded on the DOM with that animation specs, however, I would like to see if there is any workaround to this problem.

Comment: In your sandbox, both buttons make it slide up. Can't recreate what you're saying. And I tested pressing one then the other

Comment: works for me. try pressing multyple times like : up , up, up, down ,down. During the change you will see how the animation is different